# Creating a loop in Jquery for an application built on Knack

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am trying to write a js script using jquery to change the language of the UI of one application created in a platform called Knack. The problem is that (maybe because Knack uses event handlers which I don't fully understand or just due to my short JS skills) when I click somewhere in the UI the language reverts back to the original language. I am wondering is this is related to the loop? i.e, how can I force the loop to run again for every event in the page?

Thanks!

Here's my script:

```
// Translation script ----> Start

$(document).on('knack-view-render.any', function() {
// var time = $(".view_22 kn-rich_text kn-view");
// add time to logo section $("#knack-logo").append($("time"));

$(".field_19 .table-fixed-label span").html("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Tender");                   //english default
$(".field_45 .table-fixed-label span").html("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     Language");         //english default
$(".field_19 .kn-label span").html("Tender");                                               //english default
$(".field_45 .kn-label span").html("Language");                                         //english default
$(".table-keyword-search a").html("Search");                                            //english default
$(".kn-form-reload").html("Reload Form");                                               //english default
$(".kn-message.success").html("<div>Form successfully submitted.</div><br />");     //english default
$(".kn-message.error p").html("<p>Name is required!</p><br />");
$(".table-keyword-search input").attr("placeholder", "Search by Keyword");          //english default
$(".kn-submit input[type=submit]").attr("value", "Submit");                         //english default
$('.kn-add-filter').text('add filter');                                             //english default
});
$(document).on('knack-view-render.any', function(event, page, data, view, record, scene) {

$("#view_26 select[id=chlang]").change(function() {                                         //html document in view_26 with the <select> options
var selectedValue = $(this).val();
if (selectedValue  === 'en') {
$(".field_19 .table-fixed-label span").html("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Tender");                       //english default
$(".field_45 .table-fixed-label span").html("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Language");                     //english default
$(".field_19 .kn-label span").html("Tender");                                   //english default
$(".field_45 .kn-label span").html("Language");                             //english default
$(".table-keyword-search a").html("Search");                                            //english default
$(".kn-form-reload").html("Reload Form");                                               //english default
$(".kn-message.success").html("<div>Form successfully submitted.</div><br />");     //english default
$(".kn-message.error strong").html("<div>Name is required!</div><br />");

$(".table-keyword-search input").attr("placeholder", "Search by Keyword");          //english default
$(".kn-submit input[type=submit]").attr("value", "Submit");                         //english default
$('.kn-add-filter').text('add filter');                                             //english default
} 
else if (selectedValue  === 'fr'){
$(".field_19 .table-fixed-label span").html("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Appel d\' offre");              //replace field number and field name in desired language
$(".field_45 .table-fixed-label span").html("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Langue");                           //replace field number and field name in desired language
$(".field_19 .kn-label span").html("Appel d' offre");                           //replace field number and field name in desired language
$(".field_45 .kn-label span").html("Idiome");                                   //replace field number and field name in desired language
$(".table-keyword-search a").html("Rechercher");                                        //replace with "Search" name in desired language
$(".kn-form-reload").html("Recharger Formulaire");                                  //replace with "Reload Form" name in desired language
$(".kn-message.success").html("<div>Soumis avec Succès.</div><br />");              //replace with "Form successfully submitted."


$(".table-keyword-search input").attr("placeholder", "recherche par mots-clés");        //replace with "Search by Keyword" name in desired language
$(".kn-submit input[type=submit]").attr("value", "Enregistrer");                        //replace with "Submit" name in desired language
$('.kn-add-filter').text('ajouter filtre');                                         //replace with "add filter" name in desired language 
}
});
});

// Translation script <---- End
```

Comment: so, do you want a jquery code that triggers itself with any event?

Comment: yes, that's a good way to put it!

Answer (score 0):

If you need that a `function` or a *portion of code* `trigger` with any `event` you can do something like this, just add the necessary events to the `var events = 'some event event hover etc ...'`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function translateDoc(){
    $('h1').text('Título');
    $('input').attr('placeholder', 'Algún texto');
    $('button').text('Botón');
    $('select option:selected').text('Selector');
  }

  var events = 'mousemove click change';

  $(document).on(events, '.foo', function(event) {
    // console.log(event.type); // mousemove, click, change, etc...
    translateDoc();
  });

});
```

```css
.foo {
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Some Text" /><br /><br />
  <button type="button">Button</button><br /><br />
  <select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>Option</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that's working either in the snippet or in my code when I follow your logic.